# How validate array element based on another array element of same index in yup?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-hook-form, yup

```
const validations = {
    fullName: yup.string().required("Please enter full name").matches(/^[A-Za-z\s]+$/, 'Only letters are allowed'),
    branchId: yup.string().required("Please select branch"),
    accountCategory: yup.string().required("Please select account category"),
    accountCurrency: yup.string().required("Please select account currency"),
    accountPurpose: yup.string().required("Please select account purpose"),
    genderId: yup.string().required("Please select gender"),
    maritalStatus: yup.string().required("Please select marital status"),
    nationality: yup.string().required("Required"),
    passportPhoto: yup.string().required("Please select recent passport size photo"),
    addressTypes: yup.array(yup.string()),
    countryId: yup.array(yup.string().required("Country is required")),
    // outsideFullAddress: yup.array(yup.string().notOneOf([""], "Address is required")),
    provinceId: yup
        .array()
        .test("check-province", "Province is required", function (value) {
            const addressType = this.parent.addressTypes;
            if (
                Array.isArray(addressType) &&
                Array.isArray(value) &&
                addressType.length > 0
            ) {
                const errors = value.map((province, index) => {
                    const a = addressType[index];
                    return a === "inside" && province === null
                        ? `Province is required`
                        : undefined;
                });

                const filteredErrors = errors.map((error) => error !== undefined);

                if (filteredErrors.length > 0) {
                    throw this.createError({
                        path: "provinceId",
                        message: filteredErrors.map((error: any) => ({
                            message: error,
                            type: "province",
                        })),
                        type: "province",
                        params: {},
                        schema: yup.array(),
                    });
                }

            

                
            }
            return true;
        }),

    districtId: yup.array(yup.string().required("Required")),
    localBodyId: yup.array(yup.string().required("Required")),
    wardNumber: yup.array(yup.string().required("Required")),
    addressMobileNumber: yup.array(yup.string().required("Required")),
    email: yup.array(yup.string().required("Required").email("Please provide valid email address")),
    firstName: yup.array(yup.string().required("First name is required").matches(/^[A-Za-z\s]+$/, 'Only letters are allowed')),
    lastName: yup.array((yup.string().required("Last name is required").matches(/^[A-Za-z\s]+$/, 'Only letters are allowed'))),
};
```

I am using react hook form with yup as validation resolver. I want to validate provinceId to be required based on the corresponding index element of addressTypes array. How can i do that? And how can i throw validation error just as yup throws error ?

Comment: Please make the question short. Remove unnecessary fields. Also try to provide some examples.